# Search Functionality does not filter properly

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I was trying to implement the search function in one of the activities in order to search through the recyclerView that is setup in the fragment. However, when I change text in my SearchView all the elements from the recyclerView just disappear. It is my first time playing around with search functionality, thus no idea what to do now.

Don't know if I should mention, but I use the firebase firestore.
I should also mention that my onCreateOptionsMenu lies in the Fragment, but the onOptionsItemSelected() is in the MainActivity.

This is my Adapter. event_list_full is the copy of the event_list here.

```
 @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {

        return eventListFilter;
    }


    private Filter eventListFilter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
        List<EventPost> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
         if( charSequence == null || charSequence.length()==0){
             filteredList.addAll(event_list_full);
         } else {
             String filterPattern = charSequence.toString().toLowerCase().trim();
             for(EventPost item : event_list_full){
                 if(item.getDesc().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)){
                     filteredList.add(item);
                 }
             }
         }
         FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
         filterResults.values = filteredList;
         return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {

            event_list.clear();
            event_list.addAll((List) filterResults.values);
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    };
```

And this is the HomeFragment.java code. I also have setHasOptionsMenu(true); in the onCreateView().

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search_button);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                eventRecyclerAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {


                return false;

            }
        });

    }
```